# Accept a sentence and print the words that have same consecutive characters

Tags: java, string, character, bluej

Here is my homework:

> accept a sentence and print the words that have consecutive characters equal
>
> INPUT: an apple a day keeps
>
> OUTPUT: apple keeps

Here is what I am working on:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program1
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        String str=s.toLowerCase(); 
        int l,i=0; char c,d;int a,b,m=0;int n=0; String r=""; String res="";
        l=s.length();
        str=" "+str+" ";
        for(i=0;i<(l-1);i++)
        {
            c=str.charAt(i);
            d=str.charAt(i+1);
            a=c;
            b=d;
            m=str.indexOf(' ');
            n=str.indexOf(' ',(i+1)); 
             if(d==' ')
              { 
               m=str.indexOf(' ',(i-1));
               n=str.indexOf(' ',(i+1));
            }  
            if(a==b)
             {
               r=str.substring(m,n);
               res=res +" "+ r;
              }
            
         }
         System.out.println(res);
     }
}
```

It gets compiled, but it does not give correct output.

If I enter the above example, it returns:

```
an apple   an apple a day keeps
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: It doesn't run? You gave the input and the program printed the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to achieve the result,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
String s = sc.nextLine();
String str = s.toLowerCase();
String[] words = str.split(" ");   // Split the sentence into an array of words.

for(String ss : words){
    char previousChar = '\u0000';
    for (char c : ss.toCharArray()) {
        if (previousChar == c) {    // Same character has occurred
            System.out.println(ss);
            break;
        }
        previousChar = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by

char previousChar = 0;   // Just make sure to put a proper character here. Which the user won't type in the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: Sorry for the misinterpretation. There is no issue when you initialize the `previousChar` variable with 0. So, I have removed the comment. But I have edited the answer by initializing the `previousChar` with its default (NULL) value. So it will cause no issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
 m=str.indexOf(' ');
```

you start aat the beginning of the sentence every time, so you print the sentence from beginning to the word you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposal. :-D

**Input:** mi aasas es mass pp

**Output:** aasas mass pp

```
import java.util.*;

public class code10
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        String str=s.toLowerCase(); 

        String cadena = str;
        String delimitadores= "[ .,;?!¡¿\'\"\\[\\]]+";
        String[] palabrasSeparadas = cadena.split(delimitadores);

        for(int x=0; x<palabrasSeparadas.length; x++)
        {
          char[] tmpstr = palabrasSeparadas[x].toCharArray();
          for(int y=0; y<tmpstr.length; y++)
          {
            if((y+1) < tmpstr.length)
            {
              if(tmpstr[y] == tmpstr[y+1])
              {
                System.out.print(palabrasSeparadas[x] + " ");
              }
            }
          }
        }

        System.out.println("");
     }
}
```